# How to access form object before and after saving in django-bootstrap-modal-forms

Tags: django, forms, modal-dialog

I have following code in my view of adding a new Item. Some fields are filled via user some fields are filled in the background. If form is valid then user is redirected to a url with a parameter (slug) from added object. How can I convert this code to django-bootstrap-modal-forms way?

```
def category_view(request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
...
if request.POST:
    form = CreateItemForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.created_country = Constants.country_code
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()
        return redirect('category:item_detail', slug=obj.slug)
```

I used django-bootstrap-modal-forms in the below way. but country and user fields are not null and must be filled. These fields are not part of the form.

```
class add_person(BSModalCreateView):
  template_name = 'add_item.html'
  form_class = CreateItemForm
  success_message = 'Success: Item was created.'
  success_url = reverse_lazy('category:item_detail') # slug needed
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking, how to modify the form and the only code you do not provide is the form. But try something like this:

forms.py

```py
class BaseForm(forms.BaseForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            if isinstance(field.widget, widgets.RadioSelect):
                continue
            elif isinstance(field.widget, widgets.Select):
                field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-select'})
                continue
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})


class CreateItemForm(BaseForm):
    # your code
```

This itereates over your `FormField`s and adds the bootstrap class `form-select`, or much more important `form-control` to the widget of your field.